# QXmppClient class c'tor crash

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, xmpp

I am using the latest version of QXmpp (0.7.6) and it is crashing in the following construction:

QXmppClient *xmppClient = new QXmppClient();

Does anybody experienced the same? I have built it on Windows 7 using the MSVC2010 toolchain.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Some kind of wrong memory access... by debugging, I realized that actually it crashes in a ''connect'' sentence between two Qt classes.